# How get field from collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb

When I try `Cars.find({car1: 1}).fetch()`or `Cars.find({'car1': {model1: 1}})` I get `null`. How can I get all models from first field "car1"?

```
Cars.insert({
    car1: {
      model1: {
        year: [2012, 2013, 2014]
      },
      model2: {
        year: [2012, 2013, 2014]
      }
    },
    car2: {
      model1: {
        year: [2012, 2013, 2014]
      },
      model2: {
        year: [2012, 2013, 2014]
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here. First, you're doing an equivalency test when you should be doing an $exists test. In other words, your call is currently failing because you're asking whether car1 == 1, not whether there is a car1 field currently.

Something like this would probably work:

var cars = Cars.find({car1: {$exists : true}}).fetch();
cars[0]

Secondly, I believe your insert call is wrong for trying to add two documents at the same time. You should really only be adding one car per insert call. Try rewriting it as:

```
  Cars.insert({
    model1: {
      year: [2012, 2013, 2014]
    },
    model2: {
      year: [2012, 2013, 2014          
    }
  });

  Cars.insert({
    model1: {
      year: [2012, 2013, 2014]
    },
    model2: {
      year: [2012, 2013, 2014          
    }
  });
```

Comment: _{ 
  "_id" : "asujxopTrgDNugiFH", 
  "name" : "car1", 
  "models" : [
    { 
      "name" : "models1", 
      "year" : [ 2012, 2013, 2014 ] }, { "name" : "models2", "year" : [ 2012, 2013, 2014 ] }, { "name" : "models3", "year" : [ 2012, 2013, 2014 ] } ] }_
**How get** _models1_?
When i try `cars.find(name: "car1", models: {name: 'models1});`
I get null.
Thanks.